# Cannot access GET data

Tags: zend-framework, http-post, http-get

Let's say I have a URL: `www.example.com/setting/?title=1&test=2`

Then I have a class `Some_Controller` that extends `Zend_Controller_Action`:

```
class Test_Controller_Action extends Zend_Controller_Action {
```

Very oddly enough, when I try to fetch `GET` form data, zend's request says that there is no `GET` data at all, although if I try to submit `POST` data, everything seems fine.

```
print_r($this->_request->getParams());
```

or

```
print_r($this->_request);
```

What may be the cause of me not being able to `GET` data at all?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out trouble was with nginx config.... So zend had nothing to do with it, or partly nothing....